# Powermail and mailchimp integration in Typo3 form, where to find the url?

Tags: typo3, mailchimp, powermail

I'm using a contact form with powermail, i would like to catch every successful form send to be saved in my mailchimp audience list, maybe by url, i have found that this is possible but not the exact way to do this, how can i find this url from mailchimp ?

Answer (score 0):

LMGTFY: https://de.lmgtfy.app/#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=mailchimp%20api

reading the documentation of mailchimp reveals the full API:
https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/docs/fundamentals/#api-structure
defining the datastructure and the URL to contact.